# How to execute the appcmd on the remote server

Tags: c#, appcmd

How to execute the appcmd on the remote server? I there a way to do it with C#?

I know PSexec is one way but want to see for simpler way with C# libraries.

Comment: I don't think there is way to do it (similar to PSExec) out of the box.

Comment: The other option is WMI from what I can tell.

Comment: thank you Mike, sorry for replying so late, but I have solved this by using Microsoft.Web.Administration.dll, as the domain is accessible, but was wondering why MS has not allowing with kind of impersonation and do all by the code,  as hackers have there own way to do it, so MS not to worry :)